# AWK Command returning 0

Tags: linux, awk

While running the AWK command with the following code

```
awk -F: 'BEGIN{OFS=":"} ($2 != "*" && $2 != "!") {$2=system("openssl passwd -1 -salt {salt} {password}"); print $2}' PASS/shadow.txt > PASS/test.txt |  cat PASS/test.txt
```

When printing the command, I will receive:

"The salted password"
0

It will change the $2 to 0. But still print off the hash. Is there anyway to fix this and have 2 = the output of the  command.

I'm trying to replace all the $2 fields with a new password hash as an example project in my class and store the outcome in a new file.

Comment: `system()` returns the exit status of the command, not the output of the command.

Comment: Welcome to SO. command `$2=system("openssl passwd -1 -salt {salt} {password}")` wouldn't work in way you are thinking, `system` command will open a subshell and will NOT save output of that command into `$2` rather it will save its exit status(if I am not wrong here), so you need to let us know your complete requirement so that we can better understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like this might be what you're trying to do:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS=":" }
    $2 !~ /^[*!]$/ {
        cmd = "openssl passwd -1 -salt {salt} {password}"
        if ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ) {
            $2 = line
        }
        close(cmd)
    }
    { print }
' PASS/shadow.txt > PASS/test.txt
```

If not then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide a better example.

Answer (score 0):

The `system` command you use does not do what you expect. It returns the return code of the command you execute, not the standard output.

> **`system(expression)`:** Execute the command given by `expression` in a manner equivalent to the [`system()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html)  function defined in the System Interfaces volume of `POSIX.1-2017` and return the exit status of the command.

You can easily see this with the following:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print system("true"), system("false")}'
0 1
```

Here we exectued the commands `true` and `false` (see `man true` and `man false`) for what they do.

If you want to capture the output of a command, the `getline` command is what you need. A detailed document on the do's and don't's of `getline` can be found in [Ed Morton's All about getline](http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline). Also see [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60157542/8344060) for the implementation for this OP.